# Object variable is not changed

Tags: python, variables, object, python-multithreading

I hope I did not miss any obvious answers to this question already, but I hope you can help me with a little problem of mine.
I am currently writing a program in python to do some audio processing and feedback prediction. So far I have a class that I want to run at a 10ms interval and works on a buffer that contains audio data. I will want to fill that buffer using live input from a microfon at a later point but currently I am only using a second class, that streams chunks of audiodata into the buffer every 10ms. At least that is what it is supposed to do.

My streaming class has the following function, which is started in a new thread using
`start_new_thread(audioStreamer.streamAudio())`

```
def streamAudio(self):
    while not self.done:      
       chunk = self._readTestChunk()
       self.feedbackPred.audioStreamCallback(chunk, np.size(chunk), None, None)
       time.sleep(0.01)
```

The `self.feedbackPred` is a reference to the main class, that uses a timer to the main method every 10ms. That also works, however, the `audioStreamCallback` that is called above behaves strangely in my oppinion:

```
def audioStreamCallback(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
    print "chunk_s:", self.chunk_s     
    result = np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
        if frame_count == self.chunk_s:
            self.audioBuf = result
            print "setting audiobuf size to chunk_s"
            self.aduioBufSize = self.chunk_s
            print "after setting, self.audioBufSize:", self.audioBufSize
```

Ignore those ugly debugging prints and the overly complicated header, I will need to use that header for the microphone case. My output is unfortunatly:

```
chunk_s: 160
setting audiobuf size to chunk_s
after setting, self.audioBufSize: 0
```

I hope some of you might be able to point me to what I am doing wrong, even with this minimal code example. The funny thing is, that a smaller test case, that uses a function that runs at a specific interval and a different thread that fills a buffer works fine for me.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is:

```
self.aduioBufSize = self.chunk_s
```

and exactly `aduio..`. Just a typo

Comment: Omg *G* Ok thanks a lot, just means I was totally blind. Still better to feel emberessed a lot now than to waste more time searching!